# How do I prove that if $n≥12$, then $n=3a+7b$ for some $a≥0$, $b≥0$ where $a,b ∈ N$?

Tags: elementary-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

How do I prove that if $n\geq 12$, then $n=3a+7b$ for some $a\geq 0$, $b\geq 0$ where $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$?

I'm having trouble in solving this algebraic type of proof. Your help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to the site. A few pointers:  Make sure that the question body stands alone; repeat information from the title if it is needed. Also, see http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question for information about how to ask a good question on this site. In particular, please include additional context, such as the source of the problem, which helps other people gauge the right level of answer.

Answer (score 3):

it is enough to give such expressions for $n = 12, 13, 14.$ Any larger $n$ can then be given by simply increasing the $a$ value from one of those expressions.

$$   6 + 7 = 13 $$

make a separate check for smaller $n$

Answer (score 0):

This is basically the chicken mcnugget theorem.

It states that if $a$ and $b$ are coprime integers then the largest number that cannot be expressed as $as+bt$ with $s,t\in \mathbb N$ is $ab-a-b$.

Proof:

Every integer $n$ is expressable in the form $as+tb$ such that $s\in \{0,1,2,\dots, b-1\}$ and $t\in \mathbb Z$. To see this notice that $as$ only has to have the same value as $n\bmod b$ so that we can use $t$ to make $as+tb=n$. This is possible because $\{0,1,\dots, b-1\}$ is a full residue class $\bmod b$ and $a$ is coprime to $b$.

It is now clear that the biggest number of this form such that $t$ is negative is $(b-1)a-1(b)=ab-a-b$.

Comment: Chicken McNugget theorem? If I recall correctly, you can order nuggets in boxes of 6 and 10 which are not even coprime...

Comment: Originally, McDonald's sold its nuggets in packs of 9 and 20

Comment: Wow, those were good days then ;-)

Comment: haha, not at all, I hadn't been born yet.